# import live stock quotes onto csv file that has a for loop using python

Tags: python

This correctly gets live quotes from Interactive Brokers using ib_sync and can print them onto a Jupter platform:

```
from ib_insync import * 

stocks = ['SPY','ANGL','GDX','TMV']

test = list()
for stock in stocks:
    stock = Stock(stock, 'SMART','USD')
    contract = ib.qualifyContracts(stock)
    test.append(ib.reqMktData(contract[0],snapshot=True))
    ib.sleep(1)
for stock in test:
    print(stock.last)
```

This correctly opens a CSV file and writes text within it:

```
with open('stocks-test.csv','w',newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(['stock','price','datetime'])

f = open('stocks-test.csv','w')
f.write('hi there\n') #Give your csv text here.
```

**How do I combine the two together?**

So far I have:

```
import csv

with open('stocks-test.csv','w',newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(['stock','price','datetime'])
    spamwriter.writerow(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") )
#file closed
stocks = ['SPY','ANGL','GDX','TMV']

test = list()
for stock in stocks:
    stock = Stock(stock, 'SMART','USD')
    contract = ib.qualifyContracts(stock)
    test.append(ib.reqMktData(contract[0],snapshot=True))
    ib.sleep(1)
for stock in test:
    f.write(stock.last)
    f.write('hi there\n') #Give your csv text here.
    f.close()
```

For some reason the f.write has trouble reading a list?

Comment: The current code contains numerous `NameError`s. Please post the actual code you're running. Also, what's the type of `stock.last`?

Comment: stock.last is a ib_sync import that will return the int of the stock price. so SPY would print 288.68.

Comment: what do you mean by NameErors. Stock is an imported IB function that already works. I do notice that f.write has not worked for whatever reason on the combined version.

Comment: "Has not worked" is not enough information. Do you get an error? If so, please include the full error message in your post. Otherwise, please provide more information

Answer (score 1):

In your combined version you never declare f.  Insert the

```
f = open('stocks-test.csv','w')
```

before your for loops

Answer (score 1):

`f` is opened in `'w'` mode, which means that *one can only write `str`ings to it*. Apparently, `stock.last` is not a string, so it can't be written to the file directly. You should convert it to a string somehow, probably with `str(stock.last)`.

Comment: f.write(str(stock.last)) did the trick! thanks. now I just need to do a linebreak i think they are overlapping each other (it is only showing the last one in the list)

Comment: i probably need to do something like f.write(str(stock.last'\n'))  OR i just do a separate file and not do a loop

Comment: @JohnSmith, yep, you can do something like `f.write("{}\n".format(stock.last))` or `str(stock.last) + '\n'`

Comment: Doing str(stock.last) + '\n' ....got....  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' . I may have to try a different way I will do some research

Comment: @JohnSmith, please double check this line. _Only `stock.last`_ should be passed to `str`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I just tried  `f.write(str(stock.last)) 
        f.write('\n')`      put  1. 289.49 then a blank spot on line 2. Getting many quotes on one CSV file might be difficult...

Comment: @JohnSmith, this is exactly what it's supposed to do? It writes some data and then a newline symbol, so that the next line is actually completely empty. So, you can do: `f.write(str(stock.last) + '\n')` to write everything in one function call. Doing this with two calls is absolutely fine too.

Comment: `f.write(str(stock.last) + '\n')` gets an error message: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @JohnSmith, what does `print(type(stock.last))` output?

Comment: I think the ‘w’ is overwriting the file once per each stock in the list. So whichever stock is last in the loop is the only one that “appears”